# Добыча данных из URl

Tags: php

Как достать цифру, которая идёт после `id`?

Вид ссылки

> http://lol.com/page.php/id1

Вот это есть

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$id =$_GET['id']; } else{ exit("Вы зашил на страницу без параметра!");}
```

Но не работает.

Мне надо иммено

> http://lol.com/page.php/id1

не

> http://lol.com/page.php/id=1

Comment: explode разбей, что тут думать то

Comment: Не понятно )))Точнее я знаю что explode разбивает текст на части но я не знаю как сделать

Comment: Уточните, как веб-сервер переписывает запрос? Что попадает в `$_GET` при запросе `http://lol.com/page.php/id1`? Поставьте в начале скрипта

    print_r( $_GET); exit();

и приведите ответ тут.

Comment: пишет Вы зашил на страницу без параметра!

Comment: Не туда поставили. После `exit();` ничего не должно выполняться.

Comment: Всё решил вопрос 

$URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 
if (!preg_match("/\/id([0-9]+)$/i", $URI, $match)) {
 exit("Вы зашли без параметра");
}
 
$match[1] = $id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; //получаем текущий uri

    if (isset($link])) 
    {
           $link_id = substr($link, 13) //кол-во обрезаемых символов
           $id = $link_id; 
    } 
    else
    { 
           exit("Вы зашил на страницу без параметра!");
    }
```

Comment: какой смысл в этой строке?

    $id = $link_id;

и смысл от условия? REQUEST_URI всегда будет то :)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/u645784546/public_html/page.php on line 9

Comment: Автору нужна была переменная id, а link действительно всегда будет( как минимум "/"), затупил

Comment: логичнее условие if(strlen($link)>0)

Comment: Что у Вас на 9 строке? syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE означает, что выполняется действие с неизвестной переменной

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Url нужно парсить. Можно попробовать таким способом:

```
<?php

    $url = "http://lol.com/page.php/id1";
    // парсим url
    $url_array = explode("/", trim($url, "/"));
    // узнаем длину строки
    $len = strlen($url_array[4]);
    // выбираем все значение строки, без первых двух символов (id)
    $id = substr($url_array[4], 2, $len);
    // смотрим результат
    print $id;
?>
```

Так же можно все это вывести в отдельную функцию. Надеюсь пригодиться.

Comment: А как можно достать урл)))?

Comment: поменяй строку $url на:
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Comment: спс))))))))

Comment: Вот это хорошо робит

Answer (score 0):

Ну, во первых, `GET` параметры передаются после знака ?

В вашем случае http://lol.com/page.php?id=1

Comment: А как сделать что бы бралось из http://lol.com/page.php/id1

Comment: Насчёт  http://lol.com/page.php?id=1 я знаю

Answer (score 0):

```
$e = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $e[4];
```

самый простой путь :)

Answer (score 0):

Предложу еще вариант с регулярными выражениями, что охватит и такие случаи как

```
id1?wall
id1#mail
```

Ну и прочее.

```
$re= "/\/id([0-9]++)/i";
preg_match_all($re, $url, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
$url = "http://lol.com/page.php?id=126";
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
preg_match("/^id=([0-9]+)/", $parsed_url['query'], $matches);
var_dump(end($matches));
```